# How would I make my bot detect a reaction then send a message if the reaction is a specific reaction?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am making a help command that has reactions, the bot will add a reaction, then the use will react, and the bot will post the corresponding help message. I am stumped as to why my code doesn't work as it is throwing no errors.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return [':zany_face:'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === ':zany_face:') {
            message.reply('test.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('You didn\'t react in time');
    });
```

any help is received with thanks :)

Ps: I am using this off the back of an embed, so I want the embed to have a reaction on it, I have done that bit though, just not sure how to link the code effectively between the embed and the awaitreaction

Comment: I have a couple questions. Who sent the message, the bot or the user? Also, can you `console.log(reaction.emoji.name, user.id, message.author.id)` in your filter function?

Comment: the user sends the command =help, then the bot sends the help embed, the user reacts with the necessary emoji, the bot deletes the original help embed and sends the associated help embed with the emoji - the reaction is added to the bot's fist embed - it would probably be easier to show you, feel free to add my dc: Proto#4992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => !user.bot && user.id ==usr.id; //makes sure only the message author can react

let msg = message.channel.send("React to me!")

//creates a collector on the message for 5 seconds
let collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 5000 });
//opens the reaction collector
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, collector) => {
    //checks which reaction was given
    const chosen = reaction.emoji.name;

    if(chosen == "EMOJIHERE"){
        //removes the user's reaction
        msg.reactions.get("EMOJIHERE").remove(message.author.id).catch(allerrors)
        //sends a message back
        message.channel.send("This is an answer.")
    }
})
```